# is there a way to display less digits in common lisp when using double float?

Tags: common-lisp

I'm learning how to use the antik package in Common Lisp.

I have set `(setf *read-default-float-format* 'double-float)` in my `.sbclrc` and I'm using emacs + sly. Is there a way to have less digits in the output of calculations while keeping the precision? I would like to have something like the output of Octave which returns exp(1.0) as 2.7183

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Lisp implementations typically go to some lengths to be *correct*, and in particular they try to make it be the case that if you print something and read it back you get something which is 'the same' where that is possible.  In particular Lisp people think it's nice that

```
(defun test-rp-consistency (&optional (proto 1.0d0))
  (let ((r (random proto)))
    (= (read-from-string (with-output-to-string (s)
                           (print r s)))
       r)))
```

is true.

However, if you don't care about that and want output that is prettier but wrong, then you can do that too.  As an example, like this:

```
(defvar *bad-float-print-pprint-dispatch* (copy-pprint-dispatch))

(defun print-float-badly (to f)
  (if *print-readably*
      ;; At least make some effort to be correct
      (prin1 f to)
    (format to "~4,2F" f)))

(set-pprint-dispatch 'float 'print-float-badly 0 *bad-float-print-pprint-dispatch*)

(defmacro with-bad-float-printing (&body forms)
  `(let ((*print-pprint-dispatch* *bad-float-print-pprint-dispatch*))
     ,@forms))
```

Obviously if simply make `*print-pprint-dispatch*` be `*bad-float-print-pprint-dispatch*` with `setf` you will get bad float printing globally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `format` together with the "f" (fixed format floating point) specification ([manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cca.htm)). For instance, to limit the number of digits after the decimal point to 4:

```
CL-USER> (format t "~,4f" (exp 1.0))
         2.7183
         NIL
```

`format` is really powerful and flexible. A very good introduction can be found in this [book](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,this answer with that of  RowPj achieved what I wanted .

Answer (score 1):

Building on Renzo's answer, you can probably define a method on `print-object` to change the default behavior:

```
(defmethod print-object ((f double-float) stream)
   (format stream "~,4f" f))
```

Read more about `print-object` here: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_pr_obj.htm

Comment: That makes just what I wanted  ,thank you so much !